# Saving Airflow PostgresOperator output to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, airflow

I have the below PostgresOperator used to run a SQL query. I want to see if I can save the output of this airflow DAG as a Pandas Dataframe.

```
section_1 = PostgresOperator(
task_id='task_id',
default_args=args,
postgres_conn_id="db_conn_id",
sql="fetching_data.sql",
dag=dag)
```

SQL Query:

```
select cast_id, prod_id, name from sales;
```

I would like the output to be saved a Pandas Dataframe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not pass dataframe between operators. Airflow does offer the ability to pass metadata between tasks (operators) in the form of [Xcoms](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/xcoms.html) but you shouldn't use it to pass large sets of data.

To interact with dataframe you'll need to work with PostgresHook:

```
from airflow.providers.postgres.hooks.postgres import PostgresHook
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

def my_task():
    hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id="db_conn_id")
    df = hook.get_pandas_df(sql="select cast_id, prod_id, name from sales;")
    # do what you need with the df....

run_this = PythonOperator(
    task_id='postgres_task',
    python_callable=my_task,
)
```

If you want to read the query from file you can also do:

```
class SQLPythonOperator(PythonOperator):
    template_ext = PythonOperator.template_ext + ('.sql',)
    
def my_task(**context):
    query = context['templates_dict']['query']
    hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id="db_conn_id")
    df = hook.get_pandas_df(sql=query)
    # do what you need with the df....


run_this = SQLPythonOperator(
    task_id='postgres_task',
    python_callable=my_task,
    templates_dict={'query': 'fetching_data.sql'},
)
```

Alternatively you can write your own custom operator that implements the logic you wish.